# How to print p variable inside ipdb

Tags: python, pdb, ipdb

I have variable called `p` and I want to print its value inside [`ipdb`](https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb).

```py
p = 100
breakpoint()  # DEBUG
```

---

```
ipdb> help p
p expression
        Print the value of the expression.

ipdb> p
*** SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I can't to it since p has an alias inside `ipdb`. How can I force `p` to print its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `p p` command and `print` function:

```
ipdb> p p
100
ipdb> print(p)
100
```

Comment: It gives `*** TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable` error on my end even p is float value

Comment: @alper i think you have that error in your code. I mean that there is no connection between that error and printing variable value in debugger...

Comment: ah you are right, I have aliases p into `alias p pp dict(%1)`